# How do I get my header image to be responsive for all screen resolution sizes?

Tags: html, wordpress

The URL in question is http://remote.demowebsiteaddress.com

The large header image does not automatically resize itself for larger screens on desktop. I am using Divi theme for Wordpress..

Any help?

Comment: You can check [this](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/customizer-mobile/). However, I see you're using an outdated version of the theme. Updating yours might help too. [Latest Version](http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/Divi/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add can create responsive images that go across the entire screen by adding the`width` CSS property. Make sure your `body` tag has a `margin` & `padding` of 0 as well.

example:

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/xwazyd)

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but where do I add it?

Comment: in your css file for your theme.

Comment: Ah, I see. (Sorry). I just made the change.. and oops.. check it out http://remote.demowebsiteaddress.com

Comment: I am trying to fit the slider image to be at 100%

Comment: try setting the positioning to relative and increasing the ``z-index`` of the img, since the content on the bottom is clipping it. Is there a way for you to show me it's code so I can be more helpful?

Comment: can you direct me where to get the code? do i need to connect to my wp site via ftp? i am trying to figure that one out now. and hey, i really appreciate your help here

Comment: No problem! it should be in the ``wp-content/themes/**your-theme**/css**your-theme.css**``

Comment: it is blank, basically (i believe..)

Comment: Those are called partials, in CSS the @import allows you to consolidate multiple files into one. It should be in main-styles.css

Comment: .et_vertical_nav .et_pb_column_1_4 .et_pb_slider_fullwidth_off .et_pb_slide_description {width: 100; position: relative; z-index: 5;} try adding that.

Comment: Can I add it anywhere?

Comment: OK I added it... and it worked on the right and left... but on the bottom of the image it is still cut off for the two largest monitors.. and on the largest monitor it is still cut off on top quite a bit. But left to right, you nailed it

Comment: try increasing the z-index number just to make sure there is nothing with a higher z-index blocking it. try like ``z-index: 1000;``

Comment: OK I just increased it to 1000 and it is still the same as it was before. Is there some where else you could direct me?

Comment: you could try setting a bottom margin.

Comment: in the same CSS? WHat would I add?

Comment: yes, same. ``margin-bottom: 300px;`` just to see and then narrow down from there.

Comment: i added to code as shown .et_vertical_nav .et_pb_column_1_4 .et_pb_slider_fullwidth_off .et_pb_slide_description {width: 100;  margin-bottom: 300px; position: relative; z-index: 5;}    But to no avail ;(

Comment: You might have to contact the maker of your theme.

Comment: Let me bother you one more time. Only because now it is perfect for the largest screen, on all sides! But when I go to a much smaller screen, the image is cut off on the right and left. I will leave it so you can see it. I feel like this has narrowed it down?

Comment: That's great! You can add custom media queries to to affect that undesirable feaure and alter css ONLY at certain widths. here is an example ``@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color:lightblue;
    }
}``

Comment: that css applies a different background color on screens below 500px, its just an example to illustrate how to use it. You'll have to use google dev tools to help you narrow down at what screen size it jumbles up and alter that css.

Comment: Alright I'll run with that and try and figure it out... Thanks again for your help. I upped the answer. Have a good night

Comment: no problem! if you have any other questions feel free to direct message me and i'll try my best to help, have a good one!